# How to get the current URL from Browsers on Linux with python without Selenium or any web drivers?

Tags: python, linux, url

I want to know if there a way to get the current URL from Browsers like google chrome, firefox, brave etc., with python on Linux without selenium or any web drivers. I google it a lot and a cant find any solution for what i need.

Im using an estrategy with pyautogui that press f6 to focus url and ctrl c to copy to clipboar, but is not the best way to do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of that being done on [this page](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/263764/get-the-URL-currently-open-tab-of-browser).  That might give you a hint on how to approach the problem.

This [other page](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=3702&start=160) has a discussion on implementations of various coding.